# R Shiny: merge two reactive datasets and display in table with DT

Tags: r, merge, shiny, dt, reactive

I am trying to merge these two reactive datasets and join them to display a table.  Any advice? Here is the code in server.R:

```
  dataset1 <- reactive({
    result <- custom_function_call(*params in here*)
  })
    dataset2 <- reactive({
    result <- custom_function_call_v2(*params in here*)
  })




    joined_dataset <- reactive({
     result<-merge(x = dataset1(), y = dataset2(), by = "UniqueID", all = TRUE)

      result<-
        result%>%
        mutate(*dyplr code to create new cols here*)

        return(result)
        })

  output$summaryTableName <- 
    DT::renderDataTable({
      res <- joined_dataset()


      return(res)

    })
```

Error message:  Error in as.data.frame.default: cannot coerce class "c("datatables", "htmlwidget")" to a data.frame
Stack trace (innermost first):
    99: as.data.frame.default
    98: as.data.frame
    97: nrow
    96: merge.data.frame
    95: merge

Comment: Try printing `class(custom_function_call_v2(*params in here*))` and `class(custom_function_call_v2(*params in here*))`

Comment: Assuming `dataset1` and `dataset2` actually return `data.frames` your code looks correct but there's no more we can do without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your error message `cannot coerce class "c("datatables", "htmlwidget")`, I'm sure that you accidently use `DT::datatable()` in one of the datasets as mentioned in the question. The `DT::datatable()` is not something you can merge with another `data.frame`. I think you can get your codes work by removing the `DT::datatable()` from the dataset functions.

Comment: What I ended up doing was writing a function to combine the two tables and then calling that in my reactive function.

Comment: Glad to hear that.